# How do i extract the value of params object in express.js http get request

Tags: angularjs, http, express, meanjs

so i made a get request in the factory service in angular js

```
.factory('FollowUpTodaySvc', function($q, _, $http, currentUrl, TodayDateSvc) {
        var deferred_FTS = $q.defer();
    var getFollowUp = function(d) {
    // var getFollowUp = function(ob) {
var ob = {};
ob.a = "a";
ob.b = "b";
var url = currentUrl+"/api/FollowUpSearch/"+ob;           

      $http.get(url)
            .success(function(jsonData_FTS) {
console.log('%c 518-S getFollowup json Data =', 'background: white; color: red',jsonData_FTS);
                deferred_FTS.resolve(jsonData_FTS);
            })
            .error(function(error_FTS) {
```

when this request goes to the express server, I'm unable to extract the values from the params object.

Heres my server code.

```
exports.FollowUpSearch = function(req, res, next, id) {
console.log('224-psc FollowUpSearch-API  id = ', id);
console.log('397-psc FollowUpSearch-API  req.params = ', req.params);
console.log(chalk.green('%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%:     ' + "&&&&&&&&&"));
```

heres the terminal screenshot.

[image: ￼]

Second try by sending the data with

```
$http.get(url, obj)
```

here the id gets undefined.

Scenario 2. 
In ng service:

```
 var  data = {usernameOrEmail: "some email ", password: "PAssword"};

         console.log('513-S---- inside FollowUpTodaySvc ');
           var url = currentUrl+"/api/FollowUpSearch/"+d;
           // var url = currentUrl+"/api/FollowUpSearch/"+d;           
        $http.get(url, data )
```

on server

```
console.log('403-psc FollowUpSearch-API  req.params = ', req.params);
console.log('403-psc FollowUpSearch-API  req.body = ', req.body);
```

[image]

scenario 3.

changing the $http from get to post solves it, I can grab the values with req.body  object, But my question is what if i don twant to make Post request, I only want get coz it can be cached.
How do i send the data backend ?

scenario 4 - stringify

```
exports.Later_Today_P_prioritySearch = function(req, res, next, id) {

  console.log(chalk.white('354-PSC - - Environment:  inside  Later_Today_P_prioritySearch  '));

console.log(chalk.white('356-PSC - - req.body  ', req.body));
var stri_body = JSON.stringify(req.body)
console.log(chalk.white('358-PSC - - stri_body   ', stri_body));


console.log(chalk.white('356-PSC - - req.params  ', req.params));

var stringy = JSON.stringify(req.params)

console.log(chalk.white('356-PSC - - stringy   ', stringy));

console.log(chalk.white('356-PSC - - stringy Later_Today_P   ', stringy.Later_Today_P));
```

its funny it works for req.params but not for req.body

Heres the angular service

```
  var deferred_la_P = $q.defer();

    var getPriority = function(p) {
          url = currentUrl+"/api/Later_Today_P_prioritySearch/"+p;

      console.log('880-S  p =', p)

var data = { username : '$localStorage.username', email: '$localStorage.email' };

        $http.get(url, data)
```

[image]

scenario :  5  ( stringify using http.post

same code as above.

```
$http.post(url, data)
```

[image]

scenario 6:

with $http post  all that strinfigy was unnecessary

Because I can access the value using following.

console.log(chalk.white('364-PSC - - req.body.username ', req.body.username));

But the question remains: how to send data object via http get request.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use in your log statements

```
console.log('224-psc FollowUpSearch-API  id = ',JSON.stringify(id));
console.log('397-psc FollowUpSearch-API  req.params = ', JSON.stringify(req.params));
```

You should get more information of that object in this way, not only the type.

Answer (score 0):

Your first image shows that your `request.params` has something.

Anyways as per [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), the second argument to `$http.get` is a config object. The config object can now have the params. So you should change your code as below:

`$http.get(url, {params:obj})`